# emacs adding spaces to file

Tags: text, emacs, editor, display

I'm loading a text file into emacs and it is displaying a vertical column of slashes as a big blob of slashes with different spacing for each line. It displays correctly in VIM and notepad++, but not in emacs. What could cause this to happen?

[emacs display error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kUOz.png)

Comment: Can you share the file? You can sensitive information before posting it publicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because the file contains tabs, and Emacs uses a different tab width than VIM and notepad++.

You can make Emacs show what kind of whitespace there is with `M-x whitespace-mode`.

To change how Emacs displays tabs, use `M-x set-variable`, and change `tab-width`.  The Emacs default is 8, but many editors use 4 instead.